# How to Shift-click in Crafting Table in MC:PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

To fast transport items from/to the Crafting Table in the PC version you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left click</kbd>, but how can I do this in the Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [wiki for controls](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls), it seems as though this may not be a functionality that has been added yet.

Touch definitely has its limitations, but it's possible this could be added in the future as it is a very popular shortcut on PC.